# Make a podcast to get traffic

Tags: podcast

I need to make podcast,I have audacity and made a few but I am having problem converting it into a mp3 and storing it

Comment: What file type do your currently have? What version of Ubuntu do you have? What flavor (Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu) do you have? What medium are you trying to store the files to? Help us to help you.

Comment: In Audacity, simply select the whole project, then do File/Export and choose mp3.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't see a question in your post and I don't get the title. As I understand you, you already made the podcast and need to convert that file to a .mp3 file now.

I usually use [FF Multi Converter](https://github.com/Ilias95/FF-Multi-Converter/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu) to convert every thing (no matter if video or audio or whatever). Hope this helps.